# Inserting hebrew chars into MySql DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, hebrew

I have an asp.net page connected to a MySql DB.

When I try to insert/update values from the webpage into the DB
the chars are shown in the DB as question marks (I am using SP).
If i will write a query directly in the DB, It will work and the chars
will be displayed correctly.

The DB default charset is utf8, and the column collation is utf8_general_ci.

10x alot & Have a great weekend :)

Comment: What is the encoding of the web page?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually what solved my problem is adding CharSet=utf8 to the connection string.

10x alot everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your C# strings are being treated as unicode instead of UTF8

Some sample code from a snippet I had found some time ago:

```
System.Text.Encoding utf_8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

// This is our Unicode string:
string s_unicode = "abcéabc";

// Convert a string to utf-8 bytes.
byte[] utf8Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s_unicode);

// Convert utf-8 bytes to a string.
string s_unicode2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);

MessageBox.Show(s_unicode2);
```